# Eclipse Android : Make 4 ImageButtons fill screen in a raw

Tags: android, eclipse, imagebutton

Eclipse Android : I have 4 ImageButtons and I want to have then on the down buttom of the screen in a raw in the same width to be used AND FILL THE SCREEN's WIDTH TOGETHER. Can anyone help me to do this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LinearLayout with `weightSum=4` and horizontal orientation and put into this layout Buttons with weight 1. Here is example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you very much. and can you help me, how to insert them on the bottom of the screen ? android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" didn't work in LinearLayout!

Comment: You can use RelativeLayout as parent of LinearLayout and then use android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to align LinearLayout to the bottom.

Comment: thank you very much. sovled completely with some changes with your helps... :)

Comment: sorry another problem, i have 4 image buttons if i want to explain exactly, and when i use these codes, we can see a small space between image buttons and the sides of the screen, is there any way to remove this space ? thank you again. :)

Comment: I would suggest you to post another question with code and pictures.